# image download in fresco lib

Tags: android, fresco

I have a recycler view that renders a list with an image and text. This image url is retrieved from the file server by passing the image_ID and then this url is used to download the actual image.

Can this be done using fresco lib?  Can anyone suggest me how to do this using fresco lib?

Answer (score 1):

this work for me;
https://github.com/abdeldjalilfl/Fresco-Simple-usage

class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.drawee.generic.RoundingParams;
import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView;
import com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipeline;
import com.upshotdev.login.R;

/**
 * @author Abdeldjalil
 * Fresco takes care of image loading and display Using Fresco
 * dependencies implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
 * how to use this class
 * example
        Fresco.newBuilder((SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view))
            .setPlaceholderImage(R.color.grey200)
            .withProgressBar(true)
            .roundAsCircle(true)
            .setProgressBarColor(R.color.colorAccent,R.color.grey500)
            .setRoundCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setUri(Uri.parse("https://www.google.dz/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"))
            .build(this);
 *
 */
public class Fresco {
    private static Fresco loadImage;
    private SimpleDraweeView imageView;
    private Uri uri;
    private boolean withProgressBar=true;
    private boolean roundAsCircle=false;
    //
    private int ID_RES_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE=R.color.grey200;
    //
    private int ID_COLOR_BORDER_CIRCLE=R.color.colorAccent;
    //
    private int ID_COLOR_PROGRESS=R.color.colorAccent;
    private int ID_COLOR_BACKGROUND_PROGRESS=R.color.grey500;



    public static Fresco newBuilder(@NonNull SimpleDraweeView imageView) {
        loadImage=new Fresco(imageView);
        return loadImage;
    }
    private Fresco(@NonNull SimpleDraweeView imageView) {
        this.imageView=imageView;
    }

    /**
     * progress bar
     * @param withProgressBar default value: true
     *
     */
    public Fresco withProgressBar(boolean withProgressBar){
        this.withProgressBar=withProgressBar;
        return loadImage;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param placeholderImage The placeholder is shown until the image is ready.
     *                         default value : R.color.grey200
     */
    public Fresco setPlaceholderImage(@DrawableRes int placeholderImage){

        this.ID_RES_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE=placeholderImage;
        return loadImage;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param roundAsCircle default value : false
     *
     */
    public Fresco roundAsCircle(boolean roundAsCircle){
        this.roundAsCircle =roundAsCircle;
        return loadImage;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param color R.color.colorAccent
     * @param backgroundColor R.color.grey500
     *
     */
    public Fresco setProgressBarColor(@ColorRes int color, @ColorRes int backgroundColor){
        this.ID_COLOR_PROGRESS=color;
        this.ID_COLOR_BACKGROUND_PROGRESS=backgroundColor;
        return loadImage;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param color default value: R.color.colorAccent
     *
     */
    public Fresco setRoundCircleColor(@ColorRes int color){
        this.ID_COLOR_BORDER_CIRCLE=color;
        return loadImage;
    }

    public Fresco setUri(Uri uri) {

        this.uri = uri;
        return loadImage;
    }

    /**
     * start downloading the image
     */
    public void build(@NonNull Context context){
        if (imageView!=null) {

            imageView.getHierarchy().setPlaceholderImage(ID_RES_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE);

            if(uri!=null){
                imageView.setImageURI(uri);
            }
            if (withProgressBar){
                final CircleProgressBarDrawable progressBarDrawable=new CircleProgressBarDrawable();
                progressBarDrawable.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(ID_COLOR_PROGRESS));
                progressBarDrawable.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(ID_COLOR_BACKGROUND_PROGRESS));
                progressBarDrawable.setRadius(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radius_hierarchy_progress_fresco));
                //
                imageView.getHierarchy().setProgressBarImage(progressBarDrawable);
            }
            if (roundAsCircle){
                int color = context.getResources().getColor(ID_COLOR_BORDER_CIRCLE);
                RoundingParams roundingParams = RoundingParams.fromCornersRadius(6f);
                roundingParams.setBorder(color, 7.0f);
                roundingParams.setRoundAsCircle(true);
                imageView.getHierarchy().setRoundingParams(roundingParams);
            }
        }
    }
    //
    /**
     * clear cache of images using ImagePipeline
     */
    public static void clearCache(){
        //
        ImagePipeline imagePipeline = com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.getImagePipeline();
        imagePipeline.clearMemoryCaches();
        imagePipeline.clearDiskCaches();
        // combines above two lines
        imagePipeline.clearCaches();
    }




}
```

how to use!!

```
Fresco.newBuilder((SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view))
.setUri(Uri.parse("image link"))
            .build(this);
```

and for more details:

```
Fresco.newBuilder((SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view))
            .setPlaceholderImage(R.color.grey200)
            .withProgressBar(true)
            .roundAsCircle(true)
            .setProgressBarColor(R.color.colorAccent,R.color.grey500)
            .setRoundCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setUri(Uri.parse("image link"))
            .build(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fresco has a sample app that shows how to create a simple `RecyclerView.

Take a look at https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRecyclerViewFragment.java

It uses a `List<Uri>` for dummy data, which you'd have to replace with your URLs.